# c# chat bot | RetryPrompt message dynamically

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

c# chat bot : is there any way that we can control choice prompt's  RetryPrompt message dynamically?  I am using bot framework 4.0.

Comment: What is that "RetryPrompt message dynamically". Please post any relevant codes you have and the problem that we can help you solve.

Comment: Thanks Nirmal for your quick reply. wheever user try to give input other then whatever shown on the screen with choises prompty , the bot would reply back to the user with  different messages.

Comment: When you suggest the user some choices but they user ignores and sends a text, you want to get that text and reply to them depending on what they said? Is that your question?

Comment: typically just change the retry prompt property to whatever you want. Normally I'd d do that by declaring a validator for the prompt and making those choices in there. E.g. inside the AgePromptValidatorAsync function here; AddDialog(new NumberPrompt<int>(nameof(NumberPrompt<int>), AgePromptValidatorAsync));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of different ways to do this, depending on how I'm interpreting your question.

The easiest is to just add a separate `RetryPrompt`. For example, if we want to do this to the [`Multi-Turn-Prompt` sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/05.multi-turn-prompt/Dialogs/UserProfileDialog.cs#L48), we just add the `RetryPrompt` property:

```cs
private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> TransportStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // WaterfallStep always finishes with the end of the Waterfall or with another dialog; here it is a Prompt Dialog.
            // Running a prompt here means the next WaterfallStep will be run when the users response is received.
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ChoicePrompt),
                new PromptOptions
                {
                    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter your mode of transport."),
                    Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(new List<string> { "Car", "Bus", "Bicycle" }),
                    RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("That wasn't a valid option. Try again.")
                }, cancellationToken);
        }
```

This produces:

[image]

The other alternative would be to do something like what @pkr2000 said (although a little different), and use a custom validator to dynamically add the `RetryPrompt`. Something like:

```cs
AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(nameof(ChoicePrompt), ValidateChoicesAsync));

[...]

private static Task<bool> ValidateChoicesAsync(PromptValidatorContext<FoundChoice> promptContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (!promptContext.Recognized.Succeeded)
    {
        promptContext.Options.RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text($"You said \"{ promptContext.Context.Activity.Text},\" which is invalid. Please try again.");
        return Task.FromResult(false);
    }
    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

This produces:

[image]

You can do just about anything you want within the validator. Instead of using `MessageFactory.Text()`, you can pass in a completely different `Activity` like an Adaptive Card or something. You could also not set a `RetryPrompt`, instead changing the `Prompt` to whatever text/activity you want, return `false`, and then the user gets re-prompted with the new Prompt. It's really pretty limitless what you can do with a custom validator.

Comment: Excellent , thank you so much @mdrichardson, this is an excellent explanation